# How to have an optional object field in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have the function below which works fine:

```
export const optionsFunc: Function = (token: string) => {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
  };

  return options;
};
```

Now I want to modify it to add `params` to the `options` variable;
`params` needs to be a key/value and not mandatory variable;

How can I modify the `options` variable and the function parameter `params` to do that?
I'm looking for something like this in the end:

```
export const optionsFunc: Function = (token: string, params: any) => {
  const options = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  if (params) {
    const filteredParams = Object.entries(params).reduce(
      (a, [k, v]) => (v == null || v === 'null' ? a : (a[k] = v, a)), {}
    );
    options.params = filteredParams;
  }

  return options;
};
```

Comment: `params?: any`?

Comment: This is part of the question; `params` needs to be redeclared as a key/value variable. Didn't get your comment, Could you expand, please?

Comment: Did you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/weQJdw)?

Comment: Yes, worked fine. Didn't know about the `Record`. thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a `Record` to describe your object:

```
export const optionsFunc = (token: string, params?: Record<string, unknown>) => {
  const options = {
    params: {} as Record<string, unknown>,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  if (params) {
    const filteredParams = Object.entries(params).reduce<Record<string, unknown>>(
      (a, [k, v]) => (v == null || v === 'null' ? a : (a[k] = v, a)), {}
    );
    options.params = filteredParams;
  }

  return options;
};
```

Also, please don't annotate `optionsFunc` as `Function`. That throws away your types you put in the arrow function *and* the return type.

Later on, we use the `Record` again to describe `options.params` and the return type of the `reduce` call.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQJdw)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like

```
interface SomeObject {
    optionalField?: fieldType;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there other approach than declaring it as an interface? if I declare as an interface this will imply in other changes

Comment: You can do that like function(..., params?: any){...} but it isn`t prefer method. Actually any is not recommended to using